# Load and prepare a new dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, sentiment-analysis

I'm using tf to create a sentiment analysis model. Since I'm a noob of machine learning I followed a guide on the official documentation of Tensorflow to train and test a model with the IMDB_reviews dataset. It works pretty well but I wish I could train it with another dataset.

So I've downloaded this dataset: "movie_review.csv". It contains various columns and I want to access text and tag (where the tag is a positive or negative value and text is the text of the review).

What I want to do is to prepare the CSV as a dataset, access text and tag, vectorize them, and feed them to the network. There is no division between test and train, so I have to divide the file too.
So, I want to know how to:

**0**- Access the file I've downloaded and transform it into a dataset.
**1**- Access text and tag in the file, maybe without using pandas. If pandas is recommended and there is a simple way to access the file and passing to a network using TensorFlow I'll be okay with the answer.
**2**- Splitting the file in the test set and train set (I've already found a pandas solution for this actually).
**3**- Vectorize my text and tag to feed my network.
If you have an entire guide on how to do this, it'll be fine, it just has to use TensorFlow.

**Questions 0 to 3 have been answered**

Ok so, I have used the file posted to load a dataset to train the model on short sentences, but I'm having trouble with the training.
When I followed the guide to build the model for text classification I came out with this code:

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)

train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
encoder = info.features['text'].encoder

BUFFER_SIZE = 10000
BATCH_SIZE = 64

padded_shapes = ([None], ())

train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes = padded_shapes)

test_dataset = test_dataset.padded_batch(BATCH_SIZE, padded_shapes = padded_shapes)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Embedding(encoder.vocab_size, 64),
                            tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64)),
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
                            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 1, validation_data = test_dataset, validation_steps=30, callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

So, I trained my model this way (Some parts are missing, I have included all the fundamental ones). After this, I wanted to train the model with another dataset, and thanks to Andrew I have accessed a dataset created by me this way:

```
csv_dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(filepath, default_values, header=header)

def reshape_dataset(txt, tag):
    txt = tf.reshape(txt, shape=(1,))
    tag = tf.reshape(tag, shape=(1,))
    return txt, tag

csv_dataset = csv_dataset.map(reshape_dataset)

training = csv_dataset.take(10) 
testing = csv_dataset.skip(10)
```

And my problem is to adapt the dataset to the model I already have. I have tried various solution, but I get errors on the shapes.
Can somebody be so gentle to explain me how to do this? Obviously the solution for step 3 has already been posted by Andrew in his file, but I'd like to use my model with the weights I have saved during training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a great place to use Tensorflow's Dataset API. [Here's](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) a notebook/tutorial that covers how to do some basic data input and preprocessing stuff, right from Tensorflow's website!

I have also made a notebook with a quick example, answering each of your questions with implementations. You can find that [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18smWddd4oqIczVNTYQwxC42RcwyIyMFr?usp=sharing).

Comment: Wow man, thank you very much. I was wondering, why should i need default values? I don't know if I really need them or not, and i don't know their utility.

Comment: Do you know if your csv has NA/NaN values? I would doubt that your dataset does, but some csv files come with some columns not specified for certain rows. This can happen for any number of reasons. If your csv does have values NA or NaN, then you will need to tell tensorflow what you want these undefined values to be filled in as

Comment: Ah okay. To be honest I'm not sure if there are any NaN values, but I'll use the instruction anyway since I can't check 60k rows ahahahah

Comment: This problem is a lot simpler in pandas, nothing comes to mind immediately in tensorflow (you could write a loop and check every entry in the dataset?). In Pandas, to check for undefined values, just do `data_frame.isnull().values.any()`